# Can not write square and curly braces in qtcreator on mac

Tags: macos, qt-creator

I am trying to use QTCreator on a mac machine with a Spanish keyboard. I can not manage to type neither { now [ inside the editor. I have checked to see whether any keyboard shortcut was "capturing" the key combination used to type these but either I do not find it or there is none.
Any help is highly appreciated before I abandon QTCreator.

Answer (score 0):

can you try with:

CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + 8/9?

Comment: It does not do anything. It just prints the 8 or 9 characters. I am in a spanish keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by updating QTCreator to the latest version in the web. This is, in version 2.6.2 of QTCreator that comes with WT 5.0.0 the square and curly braces do not work, at least, for spanish keyboards. Updating to version 2.6.2, which comes with QT 5.0.1 they all seem to work fine.